# Cant get animation to stop after certain period of time

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to run some animations using pygame and pyganim and I want them to run when a key is pressed for a certain period of time and then stop. This is what I've got so far but I cant get the if block at the bottom to trigger, which should stop the animation. I'm assuming the time_now variable keeps updating so it's never greater the time_end.  What is wrong with my code?

```
while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_r:
            time_now = time.time()
            time_end = time.time() + 5
            runRight.stop()
            runLeft.stop()
            rollRight.stop()
            rollLeft.stop()
            standStill.stop()
            unsheathSword.play()
            if time_now >= time_end:
                print('stop')
                unsheathSword.stop()
                standStill.play()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your indentation is wrong. The line `while True:` should not be on the same indentation level as the second line.

Your example doesn't work because of

```
            time_now = time.time()
            time_end = time.time() + 5
```

It's never the case that `time_now >= time_end`; if you plug in the values, it's `time.time() >= time.time() + 5`, which is obviously **always** `False`. That's like saying that `55 >= 55 + 5`, which is `55 >= 60`, which is **always** `False`.

---

You also define both times with `time.time()` and at the same place that you use them, which will never let one of them evolve in time separately compared to the other. I suggest splitting the event trigger from the event:

```
unsheathingSword = False

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_r:
                time_unsheath_end = time.time() + 5
                unsheathingSword = True
                runRight.stop()
                runLeft.stop()
                rollRight.stop()
                rollLeft.stop()
                standStill.stop()
                unsheathSword.play()

    if unsheathingSword and time.time() >= time_unsheath_end:
        print('stop')
        unsheathSword.stop()
        standStill.play()
        unsheathingSword = False
```

Here `unsheathingSword = False` prevents that second block from infinitely executing. There are better ways of doing this, but I hope this will help you for now.

An additional benefit of spliting the things that trigger something from the handling of the consequences, is that it allows for much easier coding later on.

Putting these two blocks of code into functions is probably even better.